# Program Not Entering Second Loop?

Tags: c++

Any recommendations on how msg1.cpp can enter second loop? I compile and execute both programs and receive no error messages. When I compile and execute msg2.cpp it prompts user to 'Enter some text'. When user inputs text msg1.cpp displays user input. The issue is msg1.cpp is not prompting user 'Enter some text' because its not entering the loop.
Line 64 is when program should enter loop. Program should work because running is no longer equal to zero, its equal to one!
Not going to post msg2.cpp source code because msg2.cpp has nothing to do with my problem.

```
//msg1.cpp
/* Here's the receiver program. */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define MAX_TEXT 512
using namespace std;

struct my_msg_st {
    long int my_msg_type;
    char some_text[BUFSIZ];
    //char some_text[MAX_TEXT];
};

int main()
{
    int running = 1;
    int msgid;
    struct my_msg_st some_data;
    long int msg_to_receive = 0;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    char some_text[MAX_TEXT];
    //string input;

/* First, we set up the message queue. */

    msgid = msgget((key_t)1234, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (msgid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "msgget failed with error: %d\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
/* Then the messages are retrieved from the queue, until an end message is encountered.
 Lastly, the message queue is deleted. */

    while(running) {
        if (msgrcv(msgid, (void *)&some_data, BUFSIZ,
                   msg_to_receive, 0) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgrcv failed with error: %d\n", errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("You wrote: %s", some_data.some_text);
        if (strncmp(some_data.some_text, "end", 3) == 0) {
            running = 1;
        }
    }

    // msgctl performs control operations on system V message queue with identifier msqid
    /*if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "msgctl(IPC_RMID) failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }*/

    // Need to reset value, before entering second loop 
    // At this point enters loop, prompts user enter text
     while(running) {
        printf("Enter some text: ");
        for (int i = 1; i < running; i++){
        fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, stdin);
        some_data.my_msg_type = 1;
        strcpy(some_data.some_text, buffer);
        }
        if (msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&some_data, MAX_TEXT, 0) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgsnd failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (strncmp(buffer, "end", 3) == 0) {
            running = 0;
        }
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: The first loop runs while `while (running)` evaluates to `true` but I don't ever see `running` set to `0` or a `break` from the loop.

Comment: C++ has a boolean type. `running` seems like a boolean variable, but you've declared it as an integer. Why?

Comment: Never mind, this all looks like C code in a `.cpp` file...

Comment: Should `running = 1` have been `running = 0` in the first loop? If you fix that, you need to initializing it back to `1` before the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when `some_data.some_text` is equal to `"exit"`, you set `running` to **one**, not **zero**. You should first set it to zero to exit the first loop.

Set it to zero and then (after the first loop) set it to one.

Comment: I made that correction and program still not entering second loop!

Comment: @ep7network, did you make `running` equal to one before the second loop?

Comment: Yes. I modified running = 1, after leaving first loop!

Comment: @ep7network, so you replaced `running=1` with `running=0` in the second `if` of your first loop and added `running=1` before the first loop and it still doesn't work? Impossible.